Wrapping a C dll with complex structs in C#
I need to wrap a C dll so that it can be called from C#, the issue is that a property of the struct passed in is complex. Frustratingly the child property is only accessed internally in the C code, but it needs to be defined in the C# wrapper.
struct outer {
    ...
    unsigned int rsi;
    unsigned int flags;
    struct internal_state *state;
};

struct internal_state {
    int (*mode)(struct outer *);
    int (**id_table)(struct outer *);
    void (*flush_output)(struct outer *);
    int id;
    int id_len;
    ...
}

In the C code there are three methods, essentially init, act, end, each taking an instance of the outer struct. The offending properties are mode, id_table and flush_output, if I leave them out of the struct I can call init and it returns successfully. init sets the state property on the outer but on inspection state does not have any of the values set.
If I try to add in mode, id_table and flush_output as Func/Action types the call blows up with the following exception (unsurprisingly):

Cannot marshal field 'mode' of type 'internal_state': Non-blittable generic types cannot be marshaled.

Given the C# code does not touch the state property is there any way to "con" the C#/C code for that property?
Example C# code:
public unsafe byte[] GetData(byte[] data)
{
    var myOuter = new outer
    {
        ...
        rsi = 128,
        flags = 8
    };

    var intitResponse = Init(ref myOuter);
    var actResponse = Act(ref myOuter, 0);
    var endResponse = End(ref myOuter);

    return dataOut;
}

[DllImport("lib/aec.dll", EntryPoint = "init")]
public static extern int Init(ref outer outr);

[DllImport("lib/aec.dll", EntryPoint = "act")]
public static extern int Act(ref outer outr, nuint flush);

[DllImport("lib/aec.dll", EntryPoint = "end")]
public static extern int End(ref outer outr);

public struct outer
{
    ...
    public nuint rsi;
    public nuint flags;
    public internal_state state;
}

I have tried leaving off the complex properties but that causes the state property to not be initialized properly in the init method, even though it returns a 0 from the call.

The state field is a pointer, so you can put a field of type nint or IntPtr in the structure if you don't need to touch it. BTW unsigned int should be mapped to uint instead of nuint.
public struct outer
{
    .
    .
    .
    public uint rsi;

    public uint flags;

    private nint state;
}


I did try that after the init call where the state is created it has a 0x0000 value suggesting it's not pointing to the state that was created

I can confirm that this approach can obtain the pointer created in the C function by building a minimal example, but I cannot tell if there are any issues with other parts of your code.

You can check if Marshal.OffsetOf<outer>("state") and offsetof(struct outer, state) have the same value.

I have ended up writing a small c wrapper for this so it takes in a set of parameters and then constructs the objects there.
